# terraform Error: Cycle: data.azurerm_key_vault_secret

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

This is my first file main.tf

```
# Configure the Azure provider
provider "azurerm" {
  environment = "public"
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.azure-subscription-id
  client_id       = var.azure-client-id
  client_secret   = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure-client-secret1.value}"
  tenant_id       = var.azure-tenant-id

}
```

I have another file kv-data.tf

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "azure-client-secret1" {
  name      = "azure-client-secret"
  vault_uri = "https://kv23.vault.azure.net/"
}
```

But I get this error. What is the correct way to access keyvault secret?

> │ Error: Cycle: data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure-client-secret1,
> provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"]

Comment: You simply cannot do that. With what credentials is terraform supposed to access the key vault. Instead pass in the secret just like you pass in the other parameters, the caller needs to take care of running terraform with valid credentials.

Comment: I had the same issue but finally I got the solution.
Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74536196/where-to-save-azure-app-registration-secrets?noredirect=1#comment131581100_74536196

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this. To access Keyvault you would need credentials which is not supplied. You will have to hardcode it like other vars.