# Where to save Azure app registration secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

My questions is regarding Azure app registration secrets.

I have an app registration and its secrets (client_id, subscription_id, tenant_id and client_id)

I am able to provision the resources through terraform.

For the security purpose it is recommended to do not upload secrets to your git repo.

So my question is, where we can save these secrets so we can retrieve them at the runtime?

I have already saved them into Azure key vault and when I try to retrieve them in **providers.tf** I get an error

```
Cycle: data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client-secret, provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"], data.azurerm_key_vault.my_key_vault
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Key Vault is an ideal place to store client secrets *in general*, but this may pose a bootstrap problem - how do you authenticate yourself so that Key Vault knows it can disclose the secret to you? I'm not familiar with Terraform; does 'cycle' by any chance mean that it wants to use the client secret to authenticate itself through RBAC to the key vault in order to retrieve the client secret to authenticate itself through [ad infinitum]...?

Comment: can you share your terraform code?

Comment: Would you be able to share any Key Vault error messages that you're running into when trying to retrieve your Secret?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I have found the solution on terraform's official website

First you have to set env variables in your .zprofile

```
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=*******
export ARM_CLIENT_ID=*******
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=*******
export ARM_TENANT_ID=*******
```

Then you have to create a **variables.tf** file and then create variable blocks as

```
variable "subscription_id" {

}

variable "client_id" {

}

variable "client_secret" {

}

variable "tenant_id" {

}
```

and the last step is to access them in the **providers.tf** file

```
# Configuration options
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  features {

  }

}
```